# Says that I date formatting does not match. Also, how can I format these dates into year/month/date (python)

Tags: python, datetime

So I have a list of dates that I turned into a string called `dates_2`. I now want to define these strings into "dates" using `datetime.strptime` so that I then can use `datetime.strftime` to format them.

the dates that are within dates_2 are these:
`26/09/2021 04/12/2021 13/02/2022 11/11/2021 13/12/2022`

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

#Dates
dates = re.findall(r"[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+", txt)
dates_2 = ""
for x in dates:
    dates_2 += ' '+ x
    dates_3 = datetime.strptime(dates_2, '%d/%m/%Y')
    dates_sorted = datetime.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
print("Dates:", dates_sorted)
```

The errors that I get are these:

```
raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %

ValueError: time data ' 26/09/2021' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What is the difference between `%m` and `%M`?

Comment: If you are going to parse the whole string of dates, why bother with `findall`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the whitespace:

```
ValueError: time data ' 26/09/2021' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y'
```

The pattern does not match your string, because the string starts with a whitespace. Call `.strip()` on your string before passing it to the `datetime` functions.

Comment: omg I can't believe I didn't see that lol, thanks mate. However now it says that unconverted data remains "ValueError: unconverted data remains:  04/12/2021"

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please mark my answer as correct and upvote it if it solved the problem. If you have more questions, please start a new thread instead. Thanks!